# Can I export existing Salesforce reports by SOQL even if they were made in the SF UI?

Tags: migration, salesforce, database-migration

I am relocating our Salesforce reports from Salesforce to another tool. Salesforce has SOQL and the new system has SQL so I think the simplest way to migrate is to modify the SOQL statements to SQL, rather than recreate each report using the new tool's UI.

Can I do this? I've looked up other similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but the answers are far more complex than I can understand. I need *extremely* basic instructions on where to find the SOQL for each report in Salesforce.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce doesn't have a native tool to convert a Report to SOQL. There are a couple of workarounds to get close to a 1:1 conversion but both will still require some manual input on your part.

- **Using Change Sets**

  - Install the [Salesforce Change Set Helper Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-change-set-hel/gdjfanbphogooppaefebaaoohdcigpoi?hl=en-US)
  - Create an Outbound Change Set and add your reports as components
  - Click the `Download metadata` button (this comes from the extension)
  - Unzip the file
  - Open one of the .report files in a text editor

From here you can use an XML parser to programmatically generate a string for your `SELECT` criteria by targeting anything between the `<columns>` tags. Your  `FROM` criteria can be targeted through the `<reportType>` tags.

- **Manual**

  - Download the [Salesforce Inspector Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en)
  - Pull up your report in one window
  - In another window, open your Salesforce org and click the `<` but on the right side of your screen (this is from the Extension)
  - Click **Export Data**
  - Reference your report while writing your SOQL query

    - *Reminder that format should be something like `SELECT` **Insert column's API names comma separated**, `FROM` **Insert object API name** `WHERE` **Insert filters** `ORDER BY` **Insert column to sort by and include ASC for ascending and DESC for descending**

[Salesforce SOQL Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm)